# Pin required for accessing (smartcard) Card Authentication Slot

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, smartcard, yubikey

So let me set the stage:

I have created an Intermediate Signing Certificate by way of the Yubico walkthrough: https://developers.yubico.com/PIV/Guides/Certificate_authority.html

I made a couple changes, instead of the Digital Signature slot, I used the Card Authentication slot.  The reason for that is, by the spec and Yubikey's documentation it appears:

> This certificate and its associated private key is used to support
>   additional physical access applications, such as providing physical
>   access to buildings via PIV-enabled door locks. The end user PIN is
>   NOT required to perform private key operations for this slot.

So that seems great, however it appears in order to interact with this slot, my openssl/pkcs11 configuration requires a PIN anyways.  I could simply include the PIN in any scripted interactions with the CA but this just doesn't seem correct.

Has anyone experienced this, and or worked around it?

Comment: Just to get a use case straight: you want to create a CA that doesn't require any authentication for issuing certificates? That doesn't sound right to me in the first place.

Comment: The idea is that I want to have a CA without having to store a PIN for the other cardslots on the filesystem (or an API key for a secrets manager.)  It also means you can't use the certificate for EAPOL authentication without entering a pin, which is silly if you want to use a virtual smartcard (for instance.)

Answer (score 1):

The sole purpose of a CA is to issue digital signatures, specifically to sign the public keys of subordinate certificates;
Choosing a key function other than "digital signature" is contrary to this purpose.

Shouldn't you have the CA cert in the Digital Signature slot, and then a subordinate certificate (trusted by the EAPOL device) in the card-auth slot?